# php: glob in array (not in filesystem)

Tags: php

How do I glob for entries of an array, like [glob()](http://php.net/glob) does on the filesystem in PHP?

an example:

```
var_dump(glob_array('pattern*', array('p', 'pattern', 'pattern_123', 'wurstbrot'));
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "pattern"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "pattern_123"
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php ?

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks, but that does not implement the globbing.

Comment: Why do you guys think this is offtopic? Could you elaborate? I'm baffled!

Comment: To the guys who closed this question as off-topic (@Marcin-Orlowski VMai jaypal Rebse Jean): It is not - this is a question about a functionality inside of the php standard library. Now I know that it is called fnmatch() - check out the answer I accepted.

Comment: Yea, I can't see why this was closed to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [fnmatch()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.fnmatch.php) function

```
function glob_array($pattern, array $array, $flags = 0)
{
    return array_filter($array, function($val) use($pattern, $flags){
        return fnmatch($pattern, $val, $flags);
    });
}


print_r(glob_array('pattern*', array('p', 'pattern', 'pattern_123', 'wurstbrot')));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => pattern
    [2] => pattern_123
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not quite what I am searching for. In fact, there a huge differences between globbing and regular expressions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29

Comment: @tback Oh i got what you mean, try using fnmatch()

Comment: Nice, that's what I was searching for!